# Is there any way to reduce the miller effect on a mosfet bridge?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, mosfet-driver, full-bridge

I got miller effect on a full bridge and I'm trying to get rid of it. Is there any way to reduce the miller effect on a mosfet bridge?

I'm using opto drivers with bootstrap circuitry to drive.

Comment: Drive it harder! Amps if necessary.

Comment: Use a [cascode](https://unitedsic.com/group/sic-fets/#cascodes). Or pimp your driver.

Comment: https://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Miller_effect offers some suggestions.

Comment: Kevin has it. Drive it harder. You'll need a lot of current gain after the optos. Cascode is a lovely idea but I've never seen a power efficient cascode switch, let alone a cascoded full bridge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Either decrease the VDS swing (not always possible) or have upsize your output driver so that it can deliver higher currents (more charge).

Since it's a power stage what you're describing, I'll assume you mean how to reduce the miller plateau when switching. The miller plateau happens because, as you may know, when we want to turn on a FET we have to dump charge into the channel (i.e. charge a capacitor). However, past a certain charge level (dependent on VDS), you'll no longer be charging the gate of the FET but the Cgd capacitance instead (miller cap). This makes the Vgs of the device plateau for a short time until you've charged the cap and can keep dumping charge into the gate.

[image]

Picture from: https://www.richtek.com/Design%20Support/Technical%20Document/AN005?sc_lang=zh-CN